# Saber dimensión de un contenedor, div, aside con javascript

Tags: javascript, div

Tengo dos elementos HTML en mi Web: un **aside** y un **div**, ambos con borde, uno al lado de otro y quiero saber la dimensión para en función de ello ajustar el tamaño para que no se vea uno más pequeño que otro.
Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.
Gracias.

Agregado posteriormente:
[image: Este sería el efecto visual que no deseo]

Quiero que ambos tengan la misma altura, para ello debo conocer la altura de ambos, pues varía en mi Web según el contenido, y en función de ello, tomar la mayor y aplicársela a ambos. Pero no sé como obtener esa altura.

El código sería este:

```
<style>
    div{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    div#PanelIzquierda{
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
    }
    div#PanelDerecha{
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>

<body onLoad="ajustarTamaño()">
    <div id="PanelIzquierda">
        <h2>Contenido</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="PanelDerecha">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut eros id augue pharetra ullamcorper. Mauris consectetur, magna ut vehicula porta, elit quam bibendum nulla, a dapibus tellus risus in dui. Phasellus lobortis risus ut est vestibulum, non molestie nibh dapibus. Aliquam bibendum tincidunt mi nec molestie. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse varius laoreet urna, hendrerit ultricies dolor interdum sed. Sed in neque eu urna consectetur vehicula eu non metus. Donec laoreet leo neque, ut dignissim diam feugiat id. Vestibulum vel nisl et lectus iaculis ultrices et sit amet felis. Quisque a urna maximus, efficitur magna sit amet, condimentum urna. Mauris vitae urna vestibulum, dignissim tortor ut, finibus ante.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Disculpen mi ignorancia, soy novato en esto. Muchas gracias

Comment: el como depende de como este el `css` de los elementos a modificar. Por favor, muestranos que tienes para saber como seguir. Salu2

Comment: Deberías de agregar el CSS que tienes actualmente para dichos elementos.

Comment: He agregado más info, Gracias.

Comment: @los datos que quieres puedes obtener en herramientas de desarrollador, en inspeccionar

Comment: pero no es lo que quiero

Comment: quiero que se haga con javascript, pues tengo elementos desplegables que modifican el tamaño del div constantemente

Comment: El sitio es más complejo que lo que puse en la imagen, pero sería difícil de comprender a la primera, por eso pongo ese ejemplo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías usar el valor `clientWidth` y `clientHeight` para obtener su anchura y altura correspondientes.

```js
function ajustarTamaño(){
  var panelIzquierda = document.getElementById("PanelIzquierda");
  var panelDerecha = document.getElementById("PanelDerecha");
  
  console.log(panelIzquierda.clientWidth);
  console.log(panelIzquierda.clientHeight);
  
  console.log(panelDerecha.clientWidth);
  console.log(panelDerecha.clientHeight);
}
```

```css
    div{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    div#PanelIzquierda{
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
    }
    div#PanelDerecha{
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<body onLoad="ajustarTamaño()">
    <div id="PanelIzquierda">
        <h2>Contenido</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="PanelDerecha">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut eros id augue pharetra ullamcorper. Mauris consectetur, magna ut vehicula porta, elit quam bibendum nulla, a dapibus tellus risus in dui. Phasellus lobortis risus ut est vestibulum, non molestie nibh dapibus. Aliquam bibendum tincidunt mi nec molestie. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse varius laoreet urna, hendrerit ultricies dolor interdum sed. Sed in neque eu urna consectetur vehicula eu non metus. Donec laoreet leo neque, ut dignissim diam feugiat id. Vestibulum vel nisl et lectus iaculis ultrices et sit amet felis. Quisque a urna maximus, efficitur magna sit amet, condimentum urna. Mauris vitae urna vestibulum, dignissim tortor ut, finibus ante.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, había probado de otras formas, como

Comment: document.getElementById("PanelIzquierda").style.height

Comment: document.getElementById("PanelIzquierda").offsetHeight()

Comment: Y no funcionaba, muchas gracias y Feliz Navidad ya que estamos, jaja.

Comment: @Daniel Igualmente, es un placer :) [`style.height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) sería cuando has añadido la altura inline. Por el contrario, [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) devuelve la altura del elemento con el padding. El [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) incluye todo, también los bordes.