# ¿Como puedo saber la altura del contenedor con javascript?

Tags: javascript

en este contenedor tengo una altura predeterminada de 200px y cuando pongo en consola
**dropdown.height** o **dropdown.style.height**, no me sale la altura.

```
       <div id="preguntas">
        <ul id="dropdown">
          <!-- li*10>a[href="#lorem$"]#enlace${lorem$} -->
          <li><a href="#Pregunta1" id="enlace1">¿Cuanto tiempo tarda el producto en hacerse?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pregunta2" id="enlace2">¿Donde estamos?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pregunta3" id="enlace3">¿Que podemos hacer?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pregunta4" id="enlace4">¿Se admiten devoluciones?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pregunta5" id="enlace5">lorem5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pregunta6" id="enlace6">lorem6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pregunta7" id="enlace7">lorem7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pregunta8" id="enlace8">lorem8</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pregunta9" id="enlace9">lorem9</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pregunta10" id="enlace10">lorem10</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

me gustaria saber la altura del contenedor padre. gracias

Comment: Revisa a ver si esto te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41068/saber-dimensi%C3%B3n-de-un-contenedor-div-aside-con-javascript

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Saber dimensión de un contenedor, div, aside con javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41068/saber-dimensi%c3%b3n-de-un-contenedor-div-aside-con-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si querés el alto de la caja, sin tener en cuenta sus bordes o paddings necesitas el `clientHeight`

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('dropdown').clientHeight;
```

Si querés el alto de la caja incluyendo paddings y bordes, entonces necesitas el `offsetHeight`

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('dropdown').offsetHeight;
```

Para usar la propiedad `height` como te dijeron antes, debe estar sentado el height del elemento previamente. Raro que no te sirva si decís que tenés la altura seteada en 200px.

```
var height= document.getElementByIdd('dropdown').style.height
```

Fuente: [https://www.techiedelight.com/get-height-of-div-element-javascript/#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20you%20can%20use,height%20plus%20the%20vertical%20padding](https://www.techiedelight.com/get-height-of-div-element-javascript/#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20you%20can%20use,height%20plus%20the%20vertical%20padding).

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto:

```
$("#dropdown").parentElement.style.height
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Ya lo probé y lo que obtuve fue ' '

Comment: Este código es para jQuery, creo que la forma correcta debería ser document.getElementById(...) o similar

Comment: ya lo solucione.

Comment: @IgnacioCubo: si ya lo solucionaste, _ponlo como respuesta_ y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer), o acepta alguna de las otras respuestas que te haya sido más útil.